# How to get selected row value from C1FlexGrid

Tags: c#, c1flexgrid

I have C1FlexGrid in my form with multiple rows. I want to select random rows and get those selected row value.

Selection Mode:

```
this.CliAcctHolderGrid.SelectionMode = C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.SelectionModeEnum.ListBox;
```

Function Code:

```
   private void Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
   { 
       List<string> holderIdentificationId = new List<string>(); 
       if (CliAcctHolderGrid.RowSel >= 1)
       {
           for (int CliAcctHolder = 1; CliAcctHolder <= CliAcctHolderGrid.Row; CliAcctHolder++)
           {
               C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.Row rowSel = CliAcctHolderGrid.Rows[CliAcctHolder];  
               holderIdentificationId.Add((string)rowSel["HolderIdentifierId"]); 
            } 
        }  
   }
```

From the code I have done, I am getting values which I didn't selected. Getting all values from the grid. Can anyone please suggest me where I am making a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> holderIdentificationId = new List<string>();
        if ( CliAcctHolderGrid.RowSel >= 1 )
        {
            foreach(C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.Row dr in CliAcctHolderGrid.Rows.Selected)
            {
                holderIdentificationId.Add( (string)dr["HolderIdentifierId"] );
            }
    
        }
    }
```